# .each not working on json ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have json ajax..
it gives me error as "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" when I remove .each, no error occurs, my .each is totally empty but still the error..

see the code below:

```
$.ajax({
      url: final_url,
      data: final_query,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function () {
      },
      error: function () {
      },
      success: function (data) {
        if(data['return_message']=='success') {
          alert(data['somedata'][0]['one']['two']);

          $.each(data['somedata'], function(item) {
              //alert(item['one']['two']);
          });​
        }
      }
});
```

if I remove that .each , the script works fine... i even tried with

```
function (i,item)
```

still no luck
I am stuck!

I need the .each function to traverse the json array..

Comment: So what is `data['somedata']` containing?

Comment: does it work with `for(i=0;i<data['somedata'].length;i++) alert(data['somedata'][i].['one']['two']);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an invisible character at the end of your each after the semi colon try using this

```
$.ajax({
  url: final_url,
  data: final_query,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  beforeSend: function () {
  },
  error: function () {
  },
  success: function (data) {
    if(data['return_message']=='success') {
      alert(data['somedata'][0]['one']['two']);

      $.each(data['somedata'], function(item) {
          //alert(item['one']['two']);
      });
     }
  }
});
```

Just as a heads up I used the chrome console to debug this and in the vm it showed me exactly what was wrong.  It makes it easy to debug thing like this

Comment: wow there is a question mark right there but I couldn't see it unless I copied it to notepad++

Comment: yeah, I hate those invisible characters, that would be almost impossible to solve with out another tool to show the characters

Comment: I never encountered one before. I think I better be careful from now on!

Comment: @user1735921 did this fix your issue?

Comment: It is working perfectly.. I am using Atom, and I couldn't see anything there.. I have never experienced such issue in the past.. its really weird. but thanks a lot for the help